# Layout function to plot multiple maps

Tags: r, layout, grid

I need to arrange 4 different plots together in a specific way and I'm trying to use the `layout()` function, but just keep getting the wrong results.

If the code was working the way I wanted, the layout would look like this:

[image]

so the increase plot is at the top center, decrease plot is bottom center, base21 is left and base22 is right and centered vertically between the others.

Here is the code I have at this point:

```
layout_matrix <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4),  ncol = 3)

# arrange plots using gridExtra and layout
grid.arrange(
  arrangeGrob(increase_map, decrease_map, nrow = 3),
  arrangeGrob(base21_map, base22_map, ncol = 3),
  layout_matrix = layout_matrix
)
```

but it returns this:
[image]

How can I get it to arrange like the drawing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it is helpful to write out the layout visually as though you are looking at it, with `byrow=TRUE`. E.g.

```
layout_matrix <- matrix(
    c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,
      2,2,2,2,2,0,3,3,3,3,3,
      0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0),
      nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
```

Example image of how this looks using `layout`/`layout.show` in base graphics:

[image]

Comment: OP seems to have grid graphics and not base plots.

Comment: @Roland - that might be true, but it looks like the layout matrix logic is identical for *gridExtra* - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html (see 'Complex layouts')